# Backspace not working in Firefox for TextArea when reached its limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I'm trying to limit the text in textarea using JavaScript. It works fine in Chrome but when displayed in Firefox with max limit I'm unable to use backspace key to remove elements. It simply freezes in Mozilla when with max limit.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<textarea onkeypress="return textboxMultilineMaxNumber(this,5);">dfgdfg</textarea>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
  function textboxMultilineMaxNumber(txt, maxLen) {

            if (txt.value.length > (maxLen - 1)) {
                return false;
            }


    }
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hubLz0sv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try as following

```
<textarea onkeypress="return textboxMultilineMaxNumber(this,5,event);">dfgdfg</textarea>



function textboxMultilineMaxNumber(txt, maxLen,evt) {

                if (txt.value.length > (maxLen - 1) && evt.keyCode !==8) {

                    return false;
                }

        }
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hubLz0sv/17/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for keyCode

```
<textarea onkeypress="return textboxMultilineMaxNumber(this,5, event);">dfgdfg</textarea>

function textboxMultilineMaxNumber(txt, maxLen, e) {

                if (txt.value.length > (maxLen - 1) && event.keyCode != 8) {
                    return false;
                }


        }
```